# The opposite of ‘appear’ for Vue transitions?

Tags: vue.js

I’m trying to create a ‘modal’ component. It’s using a ‘v-if’ attribute for deciding whether the component is shown or not.

The Vue docs mention you can use ‘appear’ for transitions (https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#transition-on-appear), which works well.

However, when I close the modal, the element gets removed from the DOM, and the ‘leave’ transition is not trigged.

**Is there an opposite of ‘appear’ for Vue transitions?** How can I apply a leave transition when an element is removed from the DOM?

**Link of example: https://jsfiddle.net/jelledv4/3Lr79hyg/4/**

```
<transition
  appear
  enter-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-out"
  enter-from-class="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
  enter-to-class="transform scale-100 opacity-100"

  leave-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-in"
  leave-from-class="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
  leave-to-class="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
>
```

PS I could use ‘v-show’ instead of ‘v-if’ to mitigate this, but for this use-case ‘v-if’ suits better. Plus I’m wondering how I can tackle this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your provided jsfiddle, you use v-if on the parent element of the Transition components. Instead, use v-if on the child/slot of the Transition component. Otherwise, the transition components will be removed immediately.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    toggle() {
        this.show = !this.show;
    },
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle" class="fixed z-10 bg-white ml-3 mt-3 border border-gray-800">Toggle</button>
  
  <div>
    <!-- Modal background -->
    <transition
      appear
      enter-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-out"
      enter-from-class="opacity-0"
      enter-to-class="opacity-100"

      leave-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-in"
      leave-from-class="opacity-100"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"
    >
      <div  v-if="show" class="absolute left-0 top-0 w-full h-full bg-black bg-opacity-50"></div>
    </transition>
  
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <transition
      appear
      enter-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-out"
      enter-from-class="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
      enter-to-class="transform scale-100 opacity-100"

      leave-active-class="transition duration-1000 ease-in"
      leave-from-class="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
      leave-to-class="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
    >
      <div  v-if="show"  class="fixed bg-red-500 w-52 h-52 z-10 mt-14">
        <h2 >test</h2>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, that's it, thanks a lot! Very simple, but it makes sense. Feeling a bit stupid that I didn't think of it haha. Thanks again! :-)